# What GEDCOM tag is used for overseas travel?

Tags: gedcom

I have an individual who travelled by ship to England and stayed 3 years upon returning to Australia. I wish to record the details but am unsure what event to do so under. It was not immigration/emigration. Is there a tag or event within GEDCOM I would use?

Answer (score 8):

Depends on what your software does.... So far as I understand, there is no standard GEDCOM tag for this. My software allows the creation of "custom" or "user defined" tags (whatever you want to call them), so I defined an ARRIVAL and a DEPARTURE events to accommodate the two things.

Comment: I was going to answer, but this says it all.

Comment: Check how your software exports custom events. If it creates its own tag, with or without a leading underscore, then other programs won't understand it. The proper way all programs should do custom events is with an EVENt tag and a subordinate TYPE tag, e.g. 1 EVEN 2 TYPE Arrival

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find what tags are valid in a Gedcom the Gedcom standards for v5.5 are available as a pdf download from [HERE](http://www.phpgedview.net/ged551-5.pdf). As already stated there is no purpose build tag for this. The standard does allow for non-standard tags so that may be something worth exploring BUT bear in mind that they will be unique to you.

Answer (score 3):

Record the details of the stay in England with the RESI (resides at) tag.

Specify the period of stay as a date using the FROM/TO format to whatever level of detail you know it.

Include any details of the travel to, or travel from England in a NOTE.

Don't forget to source it.

e.g.:

```
1 RESI
2 DATE FROM 1835 TO 1838
2 PLAC England
2 NOTE Travelled by ship to England and stayed 3 years upon returning to Australia.
2 SOUR @S20@
```